# ¿Cómo hago para que <br /> se muestre igual en chrome, explorer, firefox, opera, etc..?

Tags: html, css3

Los saltos usando `<br />` o `<br>` no me los muestras igual en distintos navegadores, en `firefox` el salto es más alto que en `chrome` por ejemplo, qué se puede hacer para que sea igual más o menos en todo?

Comment: quizas en vez de darle un estilo a los contenedores con padding o margin para que desplacen en lugar de usar br, o bien, si o quieres asi, con css lo puede lograr

Comment: debe ser el `line-height` (alto de línea) que difiere entre los navegadores, pon un html con css de muestra y lo probamos

Answer (score 0):

No se que queres saltar, si seran parrafos, listas, divs...
yo cuando quiero pasar a una nueva linea en DIVS por ejemplo lo hago de esta manera, (depende el caso que lo crea importante).

```
<code>
<div class="separa"></div>
</code>

<code>
<style>
.separa{
width:100%;
height:15px;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la propiedad CSS line-height, para definir una altura en píxeles fijos.

De esta manera no le permites a los navegadores usar sus estilos por defecto. Un pixel mide lo mismo en todos los navegadores.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br>
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br />
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <br />
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br />
  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat<br /> 
  nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt<br />
  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  line-height: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejaria utilizar `margin` y `padding` cuando se trata de separar elementos, en este caso te conviene poner lis select al interno de un div y hacer en modo que sean en `display: block` y le agregas el margen que quieras, 
para mi es la solucion mas sencilla y limpia ☺

```css
.select {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
  <div>
     con el use del break line <br>
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    utilizando margin : <br>
      <select class="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      </select>
      <select class="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

espero que sea de ayuda